# How to save entered in particular shipping method in database in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, custom-options, shipping-methods

I am trying to create one shipping method module which has custom field named 'account no'.

So far I Have done this.
[image]

When user clicks on custom shipping, Input box is coming up.Now I am stuck in how to save data in database.

Here is my code,

view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="carrier_custom" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_AdditionalShippingBlock/js/view/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, ko, Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom'
        },

        initObservable: function () {

            this.selectedMethod = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = quote.shippingMethod();
                var selectedMethod = method != null ? method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code : null;
                return selectedMethod;
            }, this);

            return this;
        },
    });
});
```

view/frontend/web/template/view/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.html

```
<div id="my-carrier-custom-block-wrapper" data-bind="visible: selectedMethod() == 'mpcustomshipping_mpcustomshipping'">
    <div data-bind="visible: canVisibleBlock">
    Account Number
    <input type="text">
</div>
<br/>
</div>
```

Model/CustomBlockConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class CustomBlockConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfiguration;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfiguration
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfiguration
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfiguration = $scopeConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $showHide = [];
        $enabled = $this->scopeConfiguration->getValue('sr_block_config/general/enabled', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $showHide['show_hide_custom_block'] = ($enabled)?true:false;
        return $showHide;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you completed this can you please give me the solution how you have saved the value.